# Comparing similis and par

Tags: word-comparison

When giving suggestions to [a recent translation question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5289/79) I could not decide between [*similis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=similis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and [*par*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=par&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
I realized that I don't understand the difference of the two sufficiently well.
They are obviously distinct but similar words, but dictionaries are not very good for comparing almost synonyms.
How would you compare *similis* and *par*?
How are they similar and how are they different?
Is there a useful rule of thumb for differentiating them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each is an adjective but, like their antonyms *dissimilis* and *impar*, they are neither equivalent nor interchangeable.

Indicating only 'likeness', *similis* is 'similar' or 'resembling', while *par* means 'equal' (and does not imply similarity) or 'the same' in some quality (whether stated or implicit) of the noun it qualifies.

For example, *simili intervallo* is said of objects spaced at *similar* — but not precisely *equal* — distances apart, while *pari intervallo* implies that the intervals are exactly equal. Or you might say when comparing cucumbers and apples *cucumeres et mala sunt pondere paria, sed forma dissimilia*, and so on.

Comment: True. However, in Scholastic Latin, "similis" as a technical term means "having the same quality as" -- e.g. two white things or two wise men are are "similes". So in this technical sense, it is not mere resemblance but sameness.